# Content Query WebPart displays wrong Calendar Start Date

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I Have SharePoint 2013 Enterprise.  I added a CQWP and have a Calendar for the list type.  For the "Fields to Display" section for the "Description" I have inputted Start Date;

When I save the page it presents a start date of the prior day for all calendar events.  As an example I have an item for July 15 start Time of 12:00 AM and an End Time of 11:59 PM, however the CWPQ displays 2016-07-14 19:00:00

Any ideas why the wrong date displays - this is for all events in my calendar.

Comment: What time zone do you live in? What regional setting to you have in the site where the problem occur?

Comment: Central Time Zone..Where do I check for regional settings ?

Comment: Site settings, under Site Administration, click Regional Settings. From here you can set the locale, calendar, time format etc.

Comment: sorry for the delay...I checked regional settings and I have Central time selected..Sundays as the first day of the week and 8 am as start time and 5 pm as end time; Jan 1 as the first day of the year

Answer (score 0):

This link answers the issue...[Start Time & Calculated Column Wonkiness in a SharePoint Event List](http://weblogs.asp.net/zekemouseover/start-time-amp-calculated-column-wonkiness-in-a-sharepoint-event-calendar)

Comment: The link explains the answer to my question in full detail..sorry, but not sure where the confusion is...